# Applying an attribute to an interface using PostSharp

Tags: c#, interface, attributes, postsharp

I want to be able to apply an attribute to an interface so that every method in any class that implements that interface will have the attribute applied to it.

I assumed it would look something like this:

```
[Serializable]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class TestAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    ...
}
```

Yet when i apply it to an interface like below, the OnEntry/OnExit code in the attribute is never accessed when the method is called in the class implementing the interface:

```
[Test]
public interface ISystemService
{
    List<AssemblyInfo> GetAssemblyInfo();
}
```

If i apply the attribute within the implementing class itself, as below, it works fine:

```
[Test]
public class SystemService : ISystemService
{
    ...
}
```

What am i missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use:

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(..., Inheritance=MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
public sealed class TestAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
```

Or:

```
[Test(AttributeInheritance=MulticastInheritance.Multicast] 
public interface ISystemService
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am i missing/doing wrong?

interface has no implementation, thus cannot execute any ' OnEntry/OnExit code'.

I believe you should inherit from a class.

---

Additionally you can [Multicast the attribute](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.5/Default.aspx##PostSharp.HxS/UserGuide/Laos/Multicasting/Overview.html), but you need to inherit from [MulticastAttribute](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.5/Default.aspx##PostSharp.HxS/ClassRef/html/ef62c0e6-27eb-d097-0a93-b385cb2f7297.htm).

Comment: Quoting the PostSharp documentation:
"you can put a custom attribute on an interface and have it implicitly applied on all classes implementing that interface."

Ergo, if i apply it to the class and it applies it to all the methods/properties therein, then by the above statement, applying it to an interface should do the same. Right?

Comment: This applies to 'Custom Attribute Multicasting'. I provided the link in the answer.

Comment: @Dmitrii, the links are broken. Did you meant http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.0/##PostSharp-2.0.chm/html/42748720-e440-487a-a332-4c6b447d349c.htm  and   http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.0/##PostSharp-2.0.chm/html/T_PostSharp_Extensibility_MulticastAttribute.htm

Comment: At the time of the answer the links worked. Feel free to update my answer with the new links. I already don't remember :)